# 64 bit LFSR design

Tags: verilog, lfsr

I have designed a 64 bit lfsr but I think its not showing random. Its kind of regular pattern. Can anyone please check my code and see if its correct. (TAP 64,63,61,60)

```
 module lfsr (out, clk, rst);

 output reg [63:0] out;
 input clk, rst;

 wire feedback1,feedback2,feedback3;

 assign feedback1 = ~(out[63] ^ out[62]); 
 assign feedback2 = ~(out[62] ^ out[60]);
 assign feedback3 = ~(out[60] ^ out[59]);

 always @(posedge clk, posedge rst)
 begin
  if (rst)
     out = 64'b0;
  else
     out = {out[60:0],feedback3,feedback2,feedback1};
  end
 endmodule
```

Answer (score 2):

Your taps are correct (64,63,61,60) for a maximal-length LFSR, but you haven't connected them correctly. This is what you need:

```
 module lfsr (out, clk, rst);

   output reg [63:0] out;
   input clk, rst;

   wire feedback;

   assign feedback = ~(out[63] ^ out[62] ^ out[60] ^ out[59]);

   always @(posedge clk, posedge rst)
   begin
    if (rst)
       out <= 64'b0;
    else
      out <= {out[62:0],feedback};
    end

 endmodule
```

See [this playground](https://www.edaplayground.com/x/5WVv), which is implemented for a 6-tap LFSR, because a 64-tap LFSR would take rather a long time to simulate.